# Build array of objects with PactDsl for json request

Tags: dsl, pact

I have the following request that I want to build using PactDsl

`{"myTypes:[{"type1":"a", "type2":"b"}, {"type1":"c", "type2":"d"}]}`

Could someone point me out who I can generate this json using PactDsl
As maven dependency I use:

````
<dependency>
<groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
<artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
<version>4.6.6</version>
</dependency>```

I tried to follow the following post:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061221/how-to-model-named-arrays-and-objects-in-lambda-dsl-for-pact-pact-jvm-consumer>
````